# C# Can't filter anything on GridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to filter some data on my gridview in a windows form.  My database connection is good; I receive all data for the gridview. Mention that I want to do it with textbox without any button. I get this error:

```
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'
```

Here is my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Firma
{
    public partial class Cautare : Form
    {
        public Cautare()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCautareRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\gabya\Documents\Firma.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            //Citire Stoc
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [dbo].[stoc]", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {
                int n = dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["cod"].ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["marca"].ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["model"].ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["anul"].ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["piesa"].ToString();
                dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item["stoc"].ToString();
            }

        }

        private void txtCautareMarca_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dataGridView2.DataSource;
            bs.Filter = "marca '%" + txtCautareMarca.Text + "%'";
            dataGridView2 = bs;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `btnCautareRefresh` seems to indicate that the DGV does not use a datasource to begin with, so trying to strong arm a filter onto it wont work. Use the DataTable as the DataSource or use it with a BindingSource if you have reason too.  Then you can manage the filter somewhat directly

Comment: You can simply change `dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();` in `dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;`. Remove all that's left (the loop). You can filter the data with `DataTable.DefaultView`. Or, assign the DataTable to a BindingSource (if needed, if you have other controls that use the same data source to set DataBindings) and the BindingSource to the DGV.DataSource. Then filter the BindingSource. `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataAdapter` needs to be declared with `using` statements. But, you could keep the `SqlDataAdapter`, to update your database when you'll need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the last line in the code

from :

```
        dataGridView2 = bs;
```

to  :

```
dataGridView2.Datasource = bs;
```